# pdb file not generated in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am developing an application using **C#-MVC with Entity Framework(database first) *VS 2015***

I created a separate project for **Data Layer Access**. When I build this project in either DEBUG or RELASE mode, a debug file is not getting generated i.e. "**.pdb**" file.

Please let me know, how can I generate this **.pdb** file for my project?

Comment: what about this issue? Would you please share the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Thanks Jack, I did same changes as you mentioned, now pdb file gererating but  unable to hit break point when set.

Comment: Put your mouse on the breakpoint in debug mode, do you get any warning or messages? Do you enable the Microsoft symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols? You could check your output window, and it would output the detailed debug messages there.

Comment: Its working. Thanks

Comment: Hi Kishor T, Glad to know that it is helpful. I edit my answer, would you please mark it as the answer? So it is helpful for other members who meet the same issue to research and find the answer easily:)

Answer (score 28):

(1)Like this document about [how to disable the pdb file](http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.sg/2014/04/how-to-disable-generating-pdb-files.html#!/2014/04/how-to-disable-generating-pdb-files.html), please check your project property "Debug Info" option and output path:

[image]

(2)Please also check your build configuration manager, all projects use the default Debug or Release option.

(3)If still no help, you'd better to collect the detailed output/compiled information, and make sure that which dll file or pdb generated this issue.

For breakpoint issue, please enable the Microsoft symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Visual Studio 2022. Go to Properties | Build | General. Notice the dropdown under Debug symbols. [image: build debug symbols]

For all compiler versions starting with C# 6.0, there is no difference between pdbonly and full. Choose pdb file and then choose either "current platform" or "portable across platforms".

The compiler will create a .pdb file in the same directory where the compiler creates the output file (.exe or .dll). The .pdb file has the same base file name as the name of the output file.