# Visual Studio PDB file for project in same solution not generating

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have the main project referencing the Pencil.Gaming library which is compiled as a DLL. The DLL however does not generate a PDB file or is for some other reason not debuggable, so breakpoints are never hit.

[image: Binary output folder]

How would I make Visual Studio generate that file properly? I searched alot on google and here before but didn't seem to find a proper answer.

The DLL project is added as reference if that helps solving it.

Comment: there are options in VS for generating the PDBs. Are they set to None? Check project properties then, Build->Advanced

Comment: @S. Mense, As you said that you have the dll file, but no pdb file, if so, whether you have the source code for this library? If you have it, you could open the project in your VS, and then compile it in debug mode, it would have the pdb file if you set the correct project property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024320/pdb-file-not-generated-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @S. Mense, Could you get the PDB file for your library now?

Comment: Yes it worked now. I was actually changing wrong settings that seemed right to me. I found it when trying your solution.

Comment: @S. Mense, Since it has been resolved, you could post the solution as the answer(not a comment), and then mark it as the answer. So it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this you have to open the project properties of the project you want to enable debug file creation on. Then go to Build and click the "Advanced..." button at the bottom.

Now set the debug information dropdown to "full" (or whatever you want it to be).

[Screenshot of where to find it in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyXKP.png)

"Debuginformationen" is the field you want to change.